# how to subtract two datatables with linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Is there any way to subtract two datatables in order to have rows of the first datatable that are not in the second one?

I have tried .Except() method like below but it does not work for me.

```
dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable()).CopyToDataTable();
```

I think i have mistake in using this method but i could not find that?

Comment: Do you have a key? If not, when are two rows equal?

Comment: @Kobi, No i don't have key but both datatables have the same columns and of course some same rows(i mean some rows with same values).

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv/adodotnetdataset/thread/e68e60c2-b33b-43d7-8efd-11d1a9618ed1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following code to subtract two datatables from each other :

```
var query =    
    from row1 in dt1    
    where !(from row2 in dt2    
            select row2.ID)    
           .Contains(row1.ID)    
    select row1;
```

this code returns exactly what i want...

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own Comparer using [IEquailtyComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)

```
 public class CustomDataRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
    {
        public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (x[i].ToString() != y[i].ToString())
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
        {
            return obj.ToString().GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Later you can call it like:

```
CustomDataRowComparer myDRComparer = new CustomDataRowComparer();
var result2 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(),myDRComparer).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Except` will not work because the references are different. Each "copy" of a data row in memory is a different object, thus the equality comparison being made in `Except` will always return false.

You need to compare with something comparable, like row IDs. A couple ideas how to do this:

```
var rowsInFirstNotInSecond = dt1.Rows.Where(r1=>!dt2.Rows.Any(r2=>r1.ID == r2.ID));
```

Or:

```
var rowsInFirstNotInSecond = dt1.Rows.Where(r1=>dt2.FindById(r1.ID) == null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This Code works for sure:

```
var rows =dtFirst.AsEnumerable().Except(dtSecond.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
 DataTable result = null;
 if (rows.Count() != 0)
      result = rows.CopyToDataTable();
```